# PHP MySQL Prepared Statement returning no result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have an issue with my prepared statement that is being sent through PHP to my database. Can someone tell me why the below statement does not return the result? I'll just describe what I want it to do, what its doing and the code.

I have data being sent through a form that is ready to be inserted into one of my tables but I need to get a value from another table to insert.

I used to the following SELECT statement to get the tripNo based off the data entered. This query works on MySQL Workbench and returns the correct result, but it doesn't work on my php form. The result is null when I echo $tripNo.

Code:

```
$destination=$_POST['destination'];
$dateOfSail=$_POST['dateOfSail'];

$db = createConnection();

$sql="select tripNo from TripDB where dateOfSail=? AND destination=?;";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$dateOfSail,$destination);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($tripNo);
echo "tripNo: $tripNo"; //returns null value
```

There are no errors being reported so I am not sure where to investigate next as I have looked at the prepared statements examples.

Also, I have a side question. Is the method bad practice on getting a value in order to insert to a table?

Comment: *"There are no errors being reported"* - I see no error handling whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

after the bind_result you have to perform fetch:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "tripNo:  $tripNo<br />";
}
```